# java - producing charts in PDF form

Tags: java, charts, pdf

I'm looking for suggestions on the easiest way to create charts and have them printed out as PDFs.  This has to be done in Java.

I was looking at something like: http://jcckit.sourceforge.net/index.html

But I don't see how to turn those charts into PDFs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *control* this process from Java, then you could use [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) and [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) together to produce PDF reports that contain charts you generate on the fly.  Otherwise you could look at something like [Yellowfin](http://www.yellowfin.com.au/) to perform higher level reporting controlled and administered via a browser.

Answer (score 1):

[Ireport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) is what you are looking for

Comment: That looks very good. But the online API is very thin in its documentation, and the site has very few sample code. The only documentation I see is a $49 PDF.  Are there other free libraries that are well documented online?  I don't want to pay $49 just to begin testing the product.